# Distribute records based on various percentages with tsql

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a table of items with around 800k rows. I need to create a SQL statement that allows my users to pass in various percentages that will total 100% and be limited to 5 percentages. These are then used to group the rows by a group number of each percentage.

For example, a user may request rows to be split using to following random percentages (user decides percentages):

```
 1. 20%, 20%, 30%, 30% 
 2. 12%, 12%, 12%, 12%, 52%
 3. 30%, 30%, 40%
 4. 100%
```

Based on above percentages, I need to return the following:

```
Field 1    | Field 2    | Group
--------------------------------
Data       | Data       | 1
Data       | Data       | 1
```

The group would represent a number corresponding to the percentages. So for example percentages #1 above, there would be 4 groups with the first group's records being the 1st 20% of all items selected, group 2 being the next 20%, the 3rd group being the next 30%, and the 4th group being the last 30%. Therefore, if there were a total of 200 records, group 1 should have 40 records, group 2 have 40, group 3 have 60, and group 4 have 60.

Sorry if I'm over explaining this but trying to reduce any ambiguity in my question so it's clear.

This data is stored in Azure SQL so any solution provided can use anything Azure SQL and/or SQL 2016 (in most cases) offers.

Thanks in advance to the SQL geniuses out there that are sure to make me feel appreciative and inferior all at the same time! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing in the percentages is the hard part.  The work is done by `percent_rank()`:

```
with p as (
      select ind, p, (sum(p) over (order by ind) - p) as cume_p
      from (values (1, 0.2), (2, 0.2), (3, 0.3), (4, 0.4)) v(ind, p)
     )
select t.*, v.grp
from (select t.*, percent_rank() over (order by ?) as pr
      from t
     ) t cross apply
     (select max(ind)
      from p
      where p.cume_p <= t.pr
     )  v(grp);
```

Comment: Brilliant solution! I have a solution to pass in percentages and apply them to this query. Thanks!